# Как использовать mipmap?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как правильно выбирать версию/размер картинки из mipmap-ресурса?
система это делает автоматически или нужно задавать руками?

может есть пример?

при работе с Canvas необходимая версия картинки тоже выберется автоматически?

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.foobar);
d.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
d.draw(canvas);
```

**Обновление**

Картинки необходимых размеров получены и разложены по папкам,
но при вставке в ImageView изображение размытое, необходимы размер не выбран.

В чем ошибка, что сделано не так? Может есть еще какие то настройки о которых я не знаю?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_hause"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

P.S. Изображения создал из исходного через Android Studio -> res -> New -> Image Asset

Comment: также как из  drawable, система выберет автоматически

Comment: Cистема достаёт автоматически. Вообще эти папки созданы для хранения иконок приложения. И в манифесте достаются таким образом R.mipmap.ic_launcher

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно сделать файлы с одним названием, различные только разрешением, и расположенными по соответствующим папкам mipmap.
Вот размеры в пикселях для каждой плотности экрана:

```
LDPI  36×36.
MDPI 48×48.
TVDPI 64×64.
HDPI 72×72.
XHDPI 96×96.
XXHDPI 144×144.
XXXHDPI 192×192.
```

Когда плотность экрана не критична, я создаю простую папку drawable и храню все картинки в ней.
Если же плотность экрана критична, то можно высчитать размеры изображения, исходя из соотношения размера базовой картинки к соответствующему коэффициенту экрана.
За базовую плотность берется MDPI (48×48) .

```
LDPI — MDPIx0.75.
HDPI — MDPIx1.5.
TVDPI — MDPIx1.33.
XHDPI — MDPIx2.
XXHDPI — MDPIx3.
XXXHDPI — MDPIx4.
```

Во время публикации в маркете (play.google.com), понадобится ещё и иконка 512×512 и картинка для рекламы 1024×500.

В манифесте не забудьте прописать R.mipmap.your_icon_name (по умолчанию R.mipmap.ic_launcher) и система автоматически подберет иконку под плотность экрана